# sharepoint list not able to be written to using javascript

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I've made a testing application in SharePoint that will display a test, grade it and then save the test score back to SharePoint. My boss decided it would be nice if we could review the questions and answers that were entered. I created a new list with 156 rows, 78 multi-line rows for the questions and 78 yes/no for correct or not. On the delegate function I get an error,

> "The column "q1" does not exist. It may have been deleted by another
>   user......".

I can assure you that column q1 does exist. Any ideas on the issue here?

```
function updatedRecordedResults(graded) {
   graded = ingraded;
   var currentContext = new getContext(); //gets current context of SP site
   var oList = currentContext.web.get_lists().getByTitle(window.recordedResults); //gets      the list by name

   var itemCreateInfo = new SP.ListItemCreationInformation();
   this.oListItem = oList.addItem(itemCreateInfo);
   this.oListItem.set_item("Title", window.user);

   for (var i = 0; i < graded.length; i++) {
       oListItem.set_item("q" + (i + 1), window.globalTest[i].question);
       oListItem.set_item((i + 1) + "a", graded[i]);
   }

   oListItem.update();

   currentContext.context.load(oListItem);
   currentContext.context.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.updateRecordedResults), Function.createDelegate(this, this.failedupdateRecordedResults));
}

function updateRecordedResults() {
   alert("succeeded");
}

function failedupdateRecordedResults(sender, args) {
   alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
```

Comment: are you sure that `q1` is the **display name** of the field?

Comment: Yes, it was. I found that if while creating a sp list you change either the name of the list or the name of a column javascript can't find the change. I uploaded an excel file to create the list which took care of the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you change a column name or a list name after its been saved on SharePoint, javascript can no longer access it. By creating the list first in an excel sheet and uploading it to the site I was able to prevent renaming of column names in the designer.